# Looping through XML and finding the text node - Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, object

I have got the below XML.

```
var xml = '<parent1><person><child><name>Name1</name><details><data1>123</data1><data2>34567</data2></details></child></person><person><child><name>Name2</name><details><data1>123</data1><data2>34567</data2></details></child></person></parent1>';
```

I need to loop through all the children. I only care about the XML tags that has values. Below is the code I am using to loop the same.

```
addChildren($f);

  function addChildren( $parent ) {
    $parent.children().each( function( i, child ) {
        console.log(child)
        if(child.childNodes[i] && child.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3){
//I am not getting all the text nodes here even with nodtype 3 check. 
obj.push(
{}
//Push the dynamic key and value)

addChildren( $(child) );
    });
```

Expected output is

```
{name : Name1, data1 :123, data2:34567}, {name : Name2, data1 :123, data2:34567}.
```

Could someone please guide me how would I get the key (Tag) and value (text node)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var xml = '<parent1><person><child><name>Name1</name><details><data1>123</data1><data2>34567</data2></details></child></person><person><child><name>Name2</name><details><data1>123</data1><data2>34567</data2></details></child></person></parent1>';

var results = $(xml).find("child").map(function () {
    var item = {
        name: $(this).children("name").text()
    };
    $(this).children("details").children().each(function () {
        item[this.localName] = $(this).text();
    });
    return item;
}).toArray();

console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your time. Trying to find a dynamic solution for the same as the XML structure can change.

Comment: @Ashwin Use `.children("details").find("*")` instead of `.children("details").children()`. Potentially add `if ($(this).text()) { ...}`

Comment: Yes Tomalak, Thank you, I sorted that part out.

Comment: @Ashwin Be aware that this method of adding keys to the same result `item` will not work if multiple child elements have the same name. Might not be an issue with your data, you just keep it in mind.

Comment: I changed the code to this - var results = $(xml).find("person").map(function () {
    if ($(this).text()) {
    $(this).find("*").each(function () {
        item[this.localName] = $(this).text();
         });
}
    return item;
}).toArray();  $(this).text() - cant filter out child: "Name212334567" and details: "12334567" :/

Comment: Yeah child elements will not have the same name in my scenario, Tom. Thank you for the pointer. Just that '''if ($(this).text()) { ...}''' is not filtering as expected. Pretty new to this, the struggle is real.

Comment: @Ashwin If you have XML where the above does not work, update your question with it. (Next question hint: Always use sample code that covers your edge cases.)